# How to cite multiple reference in latex to apper as [1-4,6,7]

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle, cite-package

I have to cite a list papers in elsarticle template such as

```
[1,[2],[3],[4],[6],[7]
```

I want to see in latex such as

```
[1-4,6,7]
```

I found that we can use the packet `cite` (as `\usepackage{cite}`). However, when I used, it had error.

```
! Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete.<to be read again>\par
```

I think it conflict with `natbib` package. Actually, I cannot found where I used the `natbib` package. This is my configuration

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}
%% Use the option review to obtain double line spacing
%% \documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

%% Use the options 1p,twocolumn; 3p; 3p,twocolumn; 5p; or 5p,twocolumn
%% for a journal layout:
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

%% For including figures, graphicx.sty has been loaded in
%% elsarticle.cls. If you prefer to use the old commands
%% please give \usepackage{epsfig}

%% The amssymb package provides various useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
%% The amsthm package provides extended theorem environments
%% \usepackage{amsthm}

%% The lineno packages adds line numbers. Start line numbering with
%% \begin{linenumbers}, end it with \end{linenumbers}. Or switch it on
%% for the whole article with \linenumbers.
%% \usepackage{lineno}

\journal{Journal name}

\begin{document}
```

The template file is downloaded at [here](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle).
Could you suggest to me the way to achieve the above cite?

Comment: Load `hyperref` last.

Comment: I added it as your comment. It has error as ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package natbib.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help....

Comment: Yes. I added it as my current updated file. I am using elsarticle-template-num at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle

Comment: If you read `elsarticle` documentation (2nd page), you'll see that it already uses `natbib` and that you must use options `numbers` and `sort&compress` in class options or through `\biboptions` command. By the way, using `elsarticle` is a significant information for your question, so it should be mentioned there and not as a comment.

Comment: I add that in the top of my tex file. However, It has error as my comment

Comment: Could you show us something to work with?  The best would be a Minimal Working Example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). If it's not possible, at least show us your complete preamble from `\documentclass` to `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @Ignasi: I added it. I tried to solved it but it does not work

Comment: As I told you `numbers` and `sort&compress` should go in `elsarticle` options: `\documentclass[preprint,12pt,numbers,sort&compress]{elsarticle}` because `elsarticle` already loads it. So, delete `\usepackage{natbib}` from your preamble.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From 1st page of [`elsarticle`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/elsarticle/elsdoc.pdf) documentation:

[image]

and later on (page 3) when all document class options are detailed we find

[image]

All together means that we don't have to include `\usepackage{natbib}` in our preamble because `elsarticle` already does it and that first line should be like `\documentclass[12pt,number,sort&compress]{elsarticle}` (I've deleted `preprint` because it's also a default option).

`graphicx` package can also be deleted from your preamble.

And as Joseph suggest, load `hyperref` as the last package.