# Citing a range of papers? cite package error

Tags: natbib, cite-package

While citing a range of papers, i want the output to be:

> ... a range of citations  [1-4]

Not :

> ... a range of citations [1,2,3,4]

I followed the answers in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3871/citing-a-range-of-papers-using-numeric-keys) but i found the following errors:

1- while using Cite package,this error comes:

> ! Paragraph ended before \@citex was
>   complete.

2- And by using Natbib package, nothing changes.

> ... a range of citations [1,2,3,4]

here you are the used packages in my code:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}  
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
%\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{natbib}
```

Comment: Even with `\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}`?

Comment: You cannot use `cite` with `elsarticle`. I think we have a duplicate somewhre.

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82293/how-to-generate-multiple-numeric-style-citation-call-outs and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276915/how-to-cite-multiple-reference-in-latex-to-apper-as-1-4-6-7

Comment: Even with \usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}? it gives errors @Troy.

Comment: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82293/how-to-generate-multiple-numeric-style-citation-call-outs] This answer works,@ Johannes_B